# RHEL - Environment variable

Tags: environment-variables, rhel, rhel6, ab-initio

I have an environment file named `.env337_dev`. I need to run this file to set the environment before running another command. How to run this file?

Inside the file, it contains several variables like this

```
export AB_HOME=/et/dev/abinitio/sit1/abinitio-V2   #/gcc3p32   # for 32-bit
export PATH=${AB_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

Apart from `. ./.env337_dev`command which will run and set the environment, is there any other way to run this file ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the user-specific `.bashrc` (`bash` is the default shell on RHEL 6) or a system-wide `/etc/profile.d/<something>.sh`? For the first, you would edit `$HOME/.bashrc` and append a line like `. .env337_dev` (it's still run before any "regular" command, because `.bashrc` is the Bash standard personal initialization file). Second option suggests that you use an absolute path.

If this doesn't answer your question, a more specific question and/or more details would be very helpful.

Comment: I Just need to set the environments present inside this env file. is there any way to do that

Comment: What's wrong with the suggestion to put a line `. .env337_dev` into `.bashrc`?

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this ab-initio, so you should only be setting a very few environment variables, including:

```
export AB_HOME=<path-to-co>operating-system>
export PATH=$AB_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

If you are working with Ab Initio web applications:

```
export AB_APPLICATION_HUB=<path-to-application-hub>
export JAVA_HOME=<path-to-jdk>
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

and specific settings for different applications, e.g.

```
export AB_MHUB_HOME=<path-to-metadata-hub-installation>
```

Typically you put those into the file `.profile` in your home directory, which shells evaluate for interactive sessions.